# The differences between the two actions in mysql

Tags: mysql

If I have a **MySQL** dump file: **my_dump.sql**

What are the differences between the following two actions from command line?
(I don't have password for mysql)

**Action 1:**

```
 mysql -u root my_database < my_dump.sql
```

**Action 2 (consists of 3 steps):**

step 1: Login to mysql:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

step 2: use my_database:

```
use my_database
```

step 3: execute sql script in the dump file:

```
 source my_dump.sql
```

Are the above two actions doing exactly the same thing or there are some differences behind the scene?

Comment: Surely if you have the root password, you have the root password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are two different ways of performing the same task.

also specify the path of the dump file along with the sql file

For eg :

```
$> source /home/my_dump.sql;
```